# Swift choose a random image from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

Trying to add in a background image that's randomly selected from an external array. The random function is working however it's not injecting the value into the background UIImage.

Code is:

```
    let chooseImage = images.BackgroundImages
    let randomImage = chooseImage.sample()

    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: randomImage)
    print(randomImage)
```

The print does show in the correct value and I have tried "(randomImage)" inside the UIImage.

Edit: If I add "(randomImage).jpg" then the code works as intended however will swift infer each type on the device i.e. @2x,@3x etc. Do I need to use the asset name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //in case of arrImage has UIImages

    if arrImage.count > 0 {
        let randomIndex = random() % arrImage.count
        let randomImage = arrImage.objectAtIndex(randomIndex) as! UIImage
    }else{
        let randomImage = placeholderImage
    }

    //in case of arrImage has Strings

    if arrImage.count > 0 {
        let randomIndex = random() % arrImage.count
        let randomString = arrImage.objectAtIndex(randomIndex) as! String
        let randomImage = UIImage(name:randomString)
    }else{
        let randomImage = placeholderImage
    }
```

Comment: Data type is of string @Peter

Comment: make me clear chooseImage must be array right? and randomImage is not nil, right?

Comment: Random image is not nil - it's a precomposed array of strings background1,background2 etc

Comment: **Never** do `random() % something`! Google modulo bias. Use `arc4random_uniform` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
RandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.imageArr.count)))
//imageArr is array of images

imageArr[RandomNumber]
```

Try this and still you need any help ask me.

Answer (score 0):

It works successfully. It will give you different images all time when you run app

```
   imageArr = ["1.jpeg","2.jpeg","3.jpeg","4.jpeg"]
    let RandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.imageArr.count)))
    //imageArr is array of images
     let image = UIImage.init(named: "\(imageArr[RandomNumber])")

    let imageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `randomElement()` on anything that conforms to `Sequence` now